# How to remove Thumbnail form Image using ExifInterface

Tags: java, android, exif

I want to REMOVE the Thumbnail image after take a picture. I used the camera intent to launch the camera, passing the file Uri.

I've been looking for some documentation about how to Delete the thumbnail. All small examples I've seen is just to retrieve the current metadata tags, but not how to delete it.

ExifInterface only have function `ExifInterface.setAttribute(String, String)` But which one is the TAG to point null data to delete it or something similar?

Im using the support version of Exifinterface.

```
com.android.support:exifinterface:25.3.1
```

Comment: I think thumbnails are saved into separate files. Aren't they?

Comment: I don't think you can remove the thumbnail with that EXIF code. I use a different hunk of EXIF code in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Camera/EXIFRotater), culled from the AOSP, and that has a `removeCompressedThumbnail()` method on its edition of `ExifInterface`.